# calculating difference in milliseconds between 2 SAS datetime values

Tags: sas

I have start time and end time in datettime22.3 format...

```
%let datetime_start = %sysfunc(datetime(),datetime22.3) ;
%put &datetime_start.;

%let datetime_end = %sysfunc(datetime(),datetime22.3) ;
%put &datetime_end.;
```

How to get difference between &datetime_end. and &datetime_start. in milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the difference you can subtract the numbers, which gives you the difference in seconds. Then multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds. You'll also need to use %sysevalf to do the calculation.  In this example, I've kept the datetime() as a number, which is how SAS measures time, the number of seconds from Jan 1, 1960. If the data is in the datetime format as above you'll have to convert it to a number.

```
%let start = %sysfunc(datetime()) ;
%put &start.;

ods html;
proc means data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods html close;

%let end = %sysfunc(datetime()) ;
%put &end.;

%let duration = %sysevalf((&end - &start)*1000);
%put &duration;
```